# telprompt VS tel and app approval

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a requirement to get back to the app after making a call.
I am using telprompt it does the work.
My doubt is does apple approves it?

I have repeatedly seen this comment on SO   "I've submited my app that uses telpromt with shared application without the uiwebkit and has been successfully approved by apple. answered January 19, 2013 Pablo Alejandro Junge" by same guy can few more people confirm it? any app links?

[Apple doc](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHZvHjRhJH7oAuc_PaPR68TUOJjMQ) has no mention of telprompt.

Comment: Since the `telprompt` is not official Apple may remove at in future version with out notice. So even if they approve your app you may still run into trouble later on.

Comment: @rckoenes your comment is actually the correct answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `telprompt` is not official Apple may remove at in future version with out notice. So even if they approve your app you may still run into trouble later on.

Comment: Numerous people have reported no problems with Apple approval, but of course it is a possibility.  To better future proof it, you could call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:] first and if NO, fall back on "tel:".